# How does Schur determine Galois groups of truncated exponential series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

On Serge Lang (page.274 Example 8) and several algebra textbooks, it goes as 
$$f_n=\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{X^m}{m!}\qquad \operatorname{Gal}(f)=\begin{cases}
\mathfrak{S}_n& 4\nmid n\\ \mathfrak{A}_n& 4\mid n\end{cases}$$
It is claimed that the result is due to Schur, but the reference is in German and the full text is unavailable. Are there any textbook introducing it, or some review on it? And I know nothing about $f_n$, what can we say about it, such as its discriminant?

Comment: Yes, i found it also in Kostrikin's text. But I'm no sure whether it has an English version.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Lang's book is certainly severe. I'm sure several others are too.

Comment: Yes, i meant `several'. I am sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 4):

I can calculate the discriminant of $f_n$. It may be more useful to calculate 
$F_n=n! f(n)$, which is a monic polynomial of integer coefficients. 
$$\Delta=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{1}\operatorname{Res}(F_n,F'_n)=
(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\det\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & n &\ldots & \ldots  &n!\\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\ 
&&1 & n &\ldots & \ldots & n!\\
n& \ldots & \ldots & n!\\
& n& \ldots & \ldots & n! \\ 
&& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 
&&&n& \ldots & \ldots & n!\\
\end{matrix}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\det\left(\begin{matrix}
1 &  &\\
& \ddots \\ 
&&1 \\
n& \ldots & \ldots & n!\\
& n& \ldots & \ldots & n! \\ 
&& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 
&&&n& \ldots & \ldots & n!\\
\end{matrix}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(n!)^n$$
It explains why when $4|n$, one has $\operatorname{Gal}(f)\subseteq \mathfrak{A}_n$, and $4\nmid n$ not.

A text book says that the result is derived by module $p$, this means for any prime $p\leq n$, $f_n$ always has multiple root (which is clear by direct observation), and has no multiple root for primes $p>n$. If the idea works, this means that for some prime $p>n$, $f(x)$ splits into ``severe'' factors, and one can use it to get enough information of $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$, which I think impossible with routine method of module $p$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice (and short) proof of this result using Newton polygons in "On the Galois groups of the exponential Taylor polynomials", by Robert F Coleman.

A good exposition of the topic may be found here: https://mattbaker.blog/2014/05/02/newton-polygons-and-galois-groups/

Comment: It is unclear for which $p$ they look at the splitting field of $\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{X^m}{m!}\in \Bbb{Q}_p[X]$ and how they find its degree (and ramification)

Comment: Are you referring to the paper, or the blog post?

Comment: I'm asking to which $p$ look at and how to find the degree of the splitting field

Comment: The prime $p$ is chosen in the interval $(n/2,n−2]$---this is possible by Bertrand's postulate. A Newton polygon argument is then used to show that the Galois group contains a $p$-cycle. Since the Galois group is transitive, a result of Camille Jordan then implies that the Galois group contains $A_n$. The discriminant can then distinguish between $A_n$ and $S_n$ cases.

Comment: You mean a $n$ cycle. What is the ramification/residue field of the splitting field or the one generated by one root over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You might find [my diploma thesis from 2010](http://www.orges-leka.de/diploma_orges_leka.pdf) useful which looks at exactly this question and shows how Schur and Coleman did it. It is written in German though. :-)